# Adding unimplemented methods of child classes in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, methods, shortcut

I am using LibGDX for a 2D game. I have a class `BasicActor` that extends `Actor` which is a class inside the LibGDX library. By pressing **alt + 1** while coding inside the `BasicActor` Eclipse shows suggestions such as implementing methods of a parent class. For some reason it doesn't this time. It's been a while since I coded with eclipse and I want to know if there is a mistake on my side or if this simply won't work that way.

Comment: extend vs implement, there's nothing to implement if you extended some classe (unless it's abstract)

Comment: I forgot about that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The shortcut for adding unimplemented methods in a class in Eclipse is "**Alt + Shift + S + V**".

Answer (score 0):

Hum... `[ALT][1]`? I didn't know that shortcut, but in all Eclipse editions I've used there are two ways to override super-methods:

- Press `[CTRL][SPACE]` with the cursor into a class' body. A pop-up list of overridable methods and other stuff will appear.
- Execute `Source > Override/implement methods`.